# função adequada para acessar valores array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um arquivo com uma função que pega todos os registros de uma tabela, conforme abaixo.

```
window.lerTabelaListas=function()
    {
       lista=new Array();
        db.transaction(function  (tx)
        {

         tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM listas',[],function  (tx, results)
         {

             var len= results.rows.length, i;
             for(i=0; i<len; i++)
             {
               var nome=results.rows.item(i).nome
               var id=results.rows.item(i).idLista
            lista.push(nome,id)


             }


         });

    }); 
   return lista;
   }
```

Quado eu chamo essa função não consigo obter nenhum retorno, não consigo, por exemplo, fazer um `foreach` para extrair esses valores. Pelo *console log*, porém ele retorna:

```
Array(32)
0
:
"lista de: 2/3/2018"
1
:
1
2
:
"lista básica "
```

Preciso de uma ajuda galera, visto que sou iniciante no *JavaScript*.

Comment: O `executeSql` funciona de forma assíncrona, ele não "espera" o resultado para depois retornar o valor.

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi, o excecute sql funciona de forma independente,? O que/como eu poderia fazer então,

Comment: Basicamente.. O que você pode fazer é utilizar uma *Promise* ou uma função de `callback`.

Comment: valeu, vou dar uma lida sobre

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável global fora da função:

```
var resultado = window.lerTabelaListas;
console.log(resultado);

// A sua função
window.lerTabelaListas=function()
{
   lista=new Array();
    db.transaction(function  (tx)
    {

     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM listas',[],function  (tx, results)
     {

         var len= results.rows.length, i;
         for(i=0; i<len; i++)
         {
           var nome=results.rows.item(i).nome
           var id=results.rows.item(i).idLista
        lista.push(nome,id)


         }


     });

}); 
return lista;
}
```